# How to duplicate a view as a page for another view

Tags: views, 9

I have 5 views in the back office, each view contains in the display a single page with different fields and filter criteria and other configuration, I would like to gather all the 5 views/pages as 5 pages for another sixth view, is there a possible way to duplicate a view as page for another view ?

Comment: I'm not clear about what you want to do, but you can add a view to another view as an attachment, or you can embed one view into another view.

Comment: I think you'd be fighting with Views to try to make it do that, the paging is not set up to understand a situation like you've described. What you could do instead is create 5 pages, add the relevant Views block to each, then create another block which contains a custom list marked up like the pager, with links to each of the pages you created. Limit that block to view at the bottom of the content region for just the created pages, and it would get you the effect you've described